# Strange yum behavior (local repo)

Tags: centos, repository, yum

I've been spining my head for 2 hours now trying to understand how yum goes through a repo cause i'm getting a very strange behavior.

Some background:

- Local epel-7 repo on repo server
- repo was created using reposync (reposync, createrepo, repomanage)
- can see the repo find using http://local.reposerver/epel-7-x86_64/
- I can also see the files using a shell on repo server
- client is configured and has network access to repo

Epel-7 repository structure is a little different than Epel-6 structure.  It looks like this:

```
tree -d
.
├── 0
├── 2
├── 3
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d
├── e
├── f
├── g
├── h
├── i
├── j
├── k
├── l
├── m
├── n
├── o
├── p
├── q
├── r
├── repodata
├── s
├── t
├── u
├── v
├── w
├── x
├── y
└── z

30 directories
```

With all the packages under their letters/numbers

I'm saying this because the heart of my problem is that when i do a:

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="epel-7" list available
```

I get all the package allthrough the L directory....everything after is ... not there... lost... or what ever which is very strange.

I've tried clearing everything:

```
yum clean all
```

I've tried deleting the repodata on the repo server and recreate it... nothing works.

That is why i would very much like to know the internals of the yum search command... which file/db/ it calls so i can find which one is corrupted/broken.

Could it be a cache on the http server side?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your `Epel-7` repo enabled? If not `yum clean all` wont work.
From the yum manual: The  following  are  the ways which you can invoke yum in clean mode. Note that "all files" in the commands  below means  "all files  in  currently enabled  repositories".   If you want to also clean any (temporarily) disabled repositories you need to use --enablerepo='*' option. Additionally you should try rebuilding you yum metadata with: `rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db* && rpm --rebuilddb`

Comment: Well to have just the epel-7 repo information i did a disablerepo and enablerepo in my command up top.  But yes my repo is enable with a 1 priority (all my 3 repos are at 1 priority and enabled).  Just to be sure i also did a yum clear metadata but i'll rm everything first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: This question is a more general computing question (*using* CentOS) than it is programming-related so it’s *off-topic* for StackOverflow.
It would be more appropriate for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Sorry about that.  Posted on Unix and Linux.  Thanks.